# Email new lines different in mailtrap and gmail

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail, lumen

I'm using a php framework Lumen for sending the emails (SMTP).

In dev enviroment I'm using Mailtrap for testing the emails. I have the text of the email in doublequotes. Like this:

```
"exampleLine \r\n"
"exampleLine2 \r\n\r\n"
"exampleLine3 "
```

The output that Mailtrap show me is:

```
ExampleLine
ExampleLine2

ExampleLine3
```

Thats good.

But when we send the emails using sendgrid in prod environment that happened:

```
ExampleLineExampleLine2

ExampleLine3
```

It just ignore the simple new line. Only works with double.

All help will be appreciate.

`PD: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`